# When to do performance testing using jmeter in jenkins CI?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I am creating a CI pipeline for microservices using Jenkins. Now, I am confused with performance testing, I mean where should I add stage for performance testing, after deploying my microservice to server or running microservice locally and then do performance testing ?

Answer (score 2):

The short quick answer is that it depends on what you want to achieve with performance testing.

I say so because of something called [the spectrum of testing](https://twitter.com/copyconstruct/status/961787530734534656):

[image]

It's an attempt at developing a testing taxonomy that helps in understanding where different kinds of tests fall. However, despite the attempt to make the classification a binary, the reality isn’t quite as neatly delineable as depicted. That's because it depends with testing objectives.

You can find more about it and testing in:

- [Microservice Testing: A New Dawn](https://medium.com/@k.wahome/microservice-testing-a-new-dawn-aa614d31d7e9)
- [Testing Microservices, the sane way](https://medium.com/@copyconstruct/testing-microservices-the-sane-way-9bb31d158c16)

The highlight of the testing spectrum however is the two classifications established:

- **Pre-production testing**
- **Testing in production** - with three stages: *deploy*, *release*, *post-release*

In your case, if you desire to use performance testing to safeguard against regression with new releases in an automated repeatable way, then you should add it as a **deploy** phase test in your pipeline. Or even push it to **release** or **post-release** phases backed by monitoring.

**But you have to keep in mind the cost of this kind of test in an automated pipeline.**

If you want to run performance tests in an on-demand, throw away kind of way then you don't necessarily care about automation. Your performance tests can then be left out of the pipeline as pre-production tests that are run on-demand in a local (or staging) environment.

So it really depends.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what subtype of the performance testing you're executing.

Normally I wouldn't recommend having the system under test (in your case microservice) and load generator (in your case JMeter) running at the same machine because you may run into the situation when both the microservice and JMeter are struggling for the system resources hence your results will not be reliable as:

- when it comes to high loads JMeter can be **very** resource intensive
- the same applies to the application under test

So you may run into the situation when both applications are suffering from the lack of system resources so the microservice cannot respond fast enough and JMeter is not capable of sending the requests fast enough so you will get "false-negative" results.

Theoretically you can use local environments for [regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing) purposes in case when you already discovered all the [bottlenecks](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and discovered all the issues and just want to ensure that new features and/or bug fixes don't cause performance degradation but make sure to monitor the system resources to exclude the mutual interference of JMeter and the microservice, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)

Otherwise you should rather target production or production-like environment. There are [some forms of performance tests you can conduct on a scaled-down environment](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test/) but you will not be able to fully rely on the results given you got them on a local system which doesn't have production machine(s) hardware specifications.